# Run a plugin before another one

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, cppcheck

I want to make a plugin which runs `cppcheck` tool inside a `Sensor` class. In order to reuse an existing and supported plugin I would like to use `sonar-cxx` plugin to import my plugin's results.

How does it work to order plugins use in sonar-scanner? I want to be sure that the cppcheck report is created before sonar-scanner calls cxx-plugin.

Comment: Is there something to do with `basePlugin` property?

Comment: I know that SonarSource wants plugins to be independent but it clearly seems to be a problem for some plugins. Does somebody know how are the plugins calls currently sorted ?